# REST API access from inside SSO

Tags: api, rest, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

OK so I have an account using SSO credentials  and the data within this SaaS app is available via a REST api using OAUTH2 but the API is not SSO friendly or enabled so how do I (if possible) access the data via the API but the only credentials I have are managed by the SSO., I do have my api key and secret and I can generate my access token in python from another non sso account  but the sso account even tho I have the username and password I cannot get anything but a 401.. any help?

I might add , I am just an end user and have ZERO access to the actual API or data set  but I can create and edit users and access on the SaaS app I cannot however change anything with the SSO or AD

I have tried using username@domain.com/token , I have also tried  org\username and password, I have tried requesting different access-types from the OAUTH2 endpoint and the only recognized type is password. And I have tried every combination of the above trying to get the data from the API

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the third party REST API via OAuth2 then you'll need to check with the third party team if you are authorized to access that API, they may have to provide some additional permission to allow the access. If you are getting 401 then you don't have the correct credentials, please verify.